# Unable to import pytorch in spyder after installing pytorch via conda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, spyder

The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\asmjit.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Make sure you are working with the environment in Spyder on which you have installed Pytorch.

Comment: restart your kernel in spyder

Comment: I tried to do the same thing but on importing torch this error message is being displayed

Comment: I have installed pytorch through anaconda and via anaconda navigator I am launching spyder and trying to import torch